# Fullwidth child DIV inside wrapper

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I will go straight to the point.
I have a child div that has width of 100% and it is located under wrapper that has a fixed width.I was wondering how can i make the child div "break out" and have 100% full screen page width.
Code goes like this, i tried playing with relative/absolute positioning but no luck.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="banners">
        <div class="first"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div class="second"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qMYQw/)

Beside "banners" div, there are few more sections both above and bellow that div, thats the reason it "banners" are in wrapper

Comment: What's the goal of the wrapper if you don't want it to contain the other element?

Comment: If you can use jquery you can use `$(window).width();` to get the browser viewport and then change style with `setAttribute('style','')`

Comment: @yosh, there are few more sections above/bellow the banner div

Comment: @claudiu, can you explain it a bit more, im not really a jquery/js expert

Comment: Using `position: absolute`, you can force `.banners` to have the full width of the screen or the closest parent non-static block.  However, once `.banners` is out of content flow, the following elements will be affected.  Will the height of `.banners` be known?

Comment: Why ot just close the "wrapper" and open a new one once you finished with the full width? - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oGKtA

Answer (score 0):

You could add position absolute to `.banners`, but this will position the `.banners` container in an absolute position related to the above elements.

```
.banners {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/qMYQw/

Comment: Yes, that would work, but there are few more sections bellow and above banner div

Comment: If `.banners` has a specific height, you could add a margin to the next sibling element to maintain the correct position of the sibling elements following the banners.

Answer (score 0):

After your comment I updated your div here: http://jsfiddle.net/qMYQw/1/
So you give an id to your img so you can easily call it by js. Then you get the browser viewport:

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
```

and then you change the style:

```
var z = document.getElementById('changed');
z.setAttribute('style','width:'+w+'px');
```

you can put
`z.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid blue;width:'+w+'px');` if you want additional css.

If you need 50% then you can easily do this:

```
var w = (Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0))/2;
```

Also you can apply the same to the other div.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Claudiu!
This is close, but i dont know did i explained it well enough.
Currently, they are "locked" in the box, and they need to be fullwidth like this:http://i.imgur.com/Kzhzn1f.jpg