# how to override css class with an underlying class

Tags: html, css

I have written a small code of CSS which goes like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">
    the wrapper has width:1120px;  everything inside it
    <div class="callout">
        I want this to be full width rather than width 1120px
    </div><!-- end for callout -->
    other things inside it normal at width 1120px
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
```

How can I achieve this How can I disable the wrapper behavior for the specific class inside it

Comment: possible duplicate of [fullwidth-child-div-inside-wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656468/fullwidth-child-div-inside-wrapper)

Comment: You didn't write any CSS, and do you want `.callout` to be full width of the browser window?

Comment: I think u should take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote: "I have written a small code of css which goes like this"

I assume that you know this is HTML, *not* CSS. If that's *not* clear, you are missing the basics. Anyway:

(This is no copy&pastable code solution, but it explains why you can't do what you want to do easiliy and what you can do if you want to do it anyway...)

Usually you achieve full width for a block element by giving it `width: 100%`. However, percentage width values are always in relation to the parent element (in your case `.wrapper`, not the window width). You could use javascript/jQuery to get the viewport/window width and assign that to your `.callout` class. If you do that, you also have to add `.wrapper {overflow-x: visible;}` to your CSS, otherwise the `.callout`'s maximum width will still be limited to the wrapper's width.

Another solution would be to have the `.callout` DIV *not* inside the `.wrapper` DIV (but after or before it) in the HTML, so it's independent from it. Then you can simply define `width: 100%` for `.callout`. You could also have DIVs with class `.wrapper` before *and* after the `.callout` DIV.

You can also achieve an independent width by using `position: absolute` for `.callout`, however, in this case the absolutely positioned element is considered *completely* *idependent* (except the position reference), meaning that it will also have *no* vertical or horizontal space reserved for it in the parent element, which can result in content of the parent element being hidden or displayed in a not-intended way. (you'd have to insert something in the parent element that creates enough empty vertical space for your absolutely positioned child element before the parent content continues.But this solution is not so good, since the needed vertical space will always depend on screen/viewport width and on the content.

Comment: Your answers are very accurate, and useful that is why i selected it the best answer, but currently I am using VW for width it automatically adjust the width to full width depending upon screen size.

Answer (score 2):

One standard way to approach this situation is to add `.callout` beneath (and, importantly, *outside*) `.wrapper` in the structural markup...

... and then use css to push `.callout` back up the display so it no longer appears beneath `.wrapper` in the browser display.

Of course, if you take this approach, you must be sure to leave enough space for `.callout` to be moved up into.

```css
.wrapper {
width: 1120px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

div p {
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
margin: 20px;
}

.wrapper p:nth-of-type(2) {
margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.callout {
position: relative;
top: -140px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<p>the wrapper has width:1120px;</p>
<p>everything inside it</p>
<p>other things inside it normal at width:1120px</p>
</div>

<div class="callout">
<p>I want this to be full width rather than width:1120px</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to achieve it only using `html` and `css`, I think, you can do another way:

```
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    ...
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="callout">
    ...
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    ...
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 1120px;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the current markup and make no changes (as others noted), you may use `position` property like this:

**Markup**

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>parent</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>wrapper</p>
        <div class="callout">
            <p>callout</p>
        </div><!-- end for callout -->
    </div><!-- end wrapper -->
</div><!-- end parent -->
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.callout{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

**In action**

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #99ff99;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: #ff9999;
}

.callout{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #9999ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <p>parent</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>wrapper</p>
        <div class="callout">
            <p>callout</p>
        </div><!-- end for callout -->
    </div><!-- end wrapper -->
</div><!-- end parent -->
```